# Implicit parse LocalDate with Post @Consumes(MediaType.ApplicationJson)

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, java-time, localdate

this is my Endpoint in which I would like to add a "Firma" with a post request, but the `JSON` cannot implicit parse the `timestamp`.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response  addFirma(Firma firma){
    firmaFacade.create(firma);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Those are the variables of "Firma"

```
private int firm1;
private LocalDate firm2;
```

> And this is the JSON-String I sent - LocalDate is NULL

```
{
"firm1":2,
"firm2":"2017-09-09"
}
```

But whenever I use the get Request with test data, it will show me the right result:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response  findFirma() {
    List<Firma> list = firmaFacade.findAll();
    GenericEntity<List<Firma>> result = new GenericEntity<List<Firma>>(list) { };
    return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
}
```

Please help someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jackson, add the following [dependency](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create a [`ContextResolver`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) for [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html):

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cassio, but how do I use the mapper after i copy paste the code u gave me? The value is still null