# java 8 dates come in as null in spring boot put request

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest endpoint where I want to do a put request. The object I am putting has a couple of string fields, and a LocalDateTime. The strings come through just fine, but the LocalDateTime field comes in as null. Weirdly, it isn't giving me a "we can't deserialize this" error. Here is my request body.

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "description": "test2",
    "modifyDate": "2018-05-07T16:13:04.597",
    "modifyUser": "me"
}
```

]

Here is the relevant part of my pojo

```
@Column
LocalDateTime modifyDate;
```

Here's the endpoint

```
@PUT
@Path("/putJobs")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response create(@NotNull @Valid List<Job> jobs) {
    *my jobs object contains 1 job, with a null value for modifyDate*
}
```

Here is my main class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EntityScan("whatever.pojos")
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/META-INF/**/spring-bootstrap.xml"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="whatever.webservice", entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory")
public class Application {


@Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

And finally, here are my jackson java 8 dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
<version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That endpoint has nothing to do with Spring or Spring Boot. It is a Jersey endpoint and not Spring. You will need to configure Jersey correctly.

Comment: Good catch, I've added the appropriate tags. We're using both spring & Jersey here, and the patchwork for frameworks gets confusing :/

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you implemented `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` and `LocalDateTimeSerializer` or imported them from somewhere.

Once you are using the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` module, remove the `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSerialize` annotations from the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) field and let Jackson handle that for you. This module will give you a [`LocalDateTimeSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/LocalDateTimeSerializer.html) and a [`LocalDateTimeDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateTimeDeserializer.html).

Just be sure that you register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance and disable [`WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) for further details.

Comment: I've removed the annotations from my pojo and updated the question with the ObjectMapper bean from my Configuration class. Still no luck though

Comment: @Steve You are using Jersey? If so, you may want to try a `ContextResolver` for `ObjectMapper`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48172774/1426227). Also ensure that you have `jersey-media-json-jackson` in your dependencies. You also may have a class that extends `ResourceConfig` annotated with `@Component`. You can either annotate the `ContextResolver` implementation with `@Provider` or register it in the `ResourceConfig` subclass.

Comment: ContextResolver not needed with Spring Boot. ObjectMapper bean is enough. Spring Boot has it's own ContextResolver that it registers and grabs our ObjectMapper. And Spring Boot already uses jersey-media-json-jackson.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha that's what I'd thought. All the different frameworks and versions is pretty confusing. Do you have any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Comment: @Steve Only thing I can think is that your setter is not named properly.

Comment: My get request is working now, my put still won't but I think I'm close. Thanks everyone for your effort.